# Document locking in multithreading environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-agnostic, documentation, locking

We have an application that supports binary plugins (dynamically loaded libraries) as well as a number of plugins for this application. The application is itself multithreaded and the plugins may also start threads. There's a lot of locking going on to keep data structures consistent.

One major problem is that sometimes locks are held across calls from the application into a plugin. This is problematic because the plugin code might want to call back into the application, producing a deadlock. This problem is aggravated by the fact that different teams work on the base application and the plugins.

The question is: Is there a "standard" or at least widely used way of documenting locking schemes apart from writing tons of plain text?

Comment: English? No, seriously, I would be most interested in a language-agnostic way to describe locking. If you have a solution for a specific language, fire away.

Comment: What about recursive locks? Find a mutex which can be locked multiple times by the same thread.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch: While this would solve the problem, it's not that easy to implement in a legacy codebase.

Answer (score 3):

It is a theorical approach, I hope it will help you a little.

To me you can avoid this situation by redesigning the way plugins and your application are communicating (if possible).

A plugin's code is not secure. To ensure the application's flexibility and its stability you must build a standard way to exchange informations and make critical actions with plugins.

The easiest way is to avoid to manage each specific plugin behavior by defining a lock free api.
To do that you can make the critical parts of your plugins asynchronous by using ring buffer / disruptor or just an action buffer.

**EDIT**

Sorry if I argue again in the same way, but this seems to me to be like an "IO" problem.

You have concurrent access on some resources (memory/disc/network .... don't know which ones) and the need to expose them with high availability. And finally these resources cannot be access randomly without locking your application.

With a manager dedicated on the critical parts, the wait can be short enough to be imperceptible.

However this is not easily applicable to an already existing application, mostly if it is a large one.

if you don't already know this kind of stuff, I encourage you to look to the "disruptor". To me it is one of the modern basic to consider every time I work with threads.

Comment: Well, it's a good approach per se, but lock-free isn't really feasible because the problematic calls from the plugin back into the main application are mostly queries for information the plugin cannot wait for.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use Petri Net which are simple to learn and can describe very well the cooperation among the different parts of your software. In this question are described several models and tools useful to document concurrency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164187/what-tools-diagrams-do-you-use-for-modelling-multithreaded-systems. You can choose the right model according your needs.

Comment: This seems like the best approach, although I fear that writing down a Petri net for the software system will be quite a mess.

Comment: I know, unfortunately every model has some benefits and drawbacks.
My advice is limit the use of Petri Net only to describe the access to shared resources or, in general, to describe cooperations like producer-consumer. To describe the synchronization among threads, you can use the UML Activity Diagrams, which  are very good and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If your locking scheme is simple enough that you can describe it in documentation, then by all means do so. However, if deadlocks are occurring in practice, the problem may not be lack of documentation, but that the API is not serving the needs of your plugin authors. Documenting the limitations is a good first step, but removing the limitations is better.

Consider the possibilities for a deadlock on a single lock held by your code and requested by the plugin:

1. Your code is not in the middle of reading or writing, but is still holding the lock just because that's how the code was written. In that case, your code should release the lock before calling into the plugin.
2. Your code and the plugin are both reading data, and using the lock to prevent concurrent writers. In that case, use a readers-writers lock.
3. Your code is in the middle of changing data, and the plugin wants to read it. This is not generally safe; there's a reason you're using a lock to protect the entire modification, after all. Most attempts to make this safe fail in practice (it is as hard as writing lock-free code). In this case, the best thing to do is change your design so your code finishes changes before calling the plugin, or starts changes after calling the plugin.
4. Your code is in the middle of reading data, and the plugin wants to change it. Like the previous case, this is also not safe. Your code should release the lock before calling the plugin and acquire it again afterward, and assume the data have changed, re-reading anything you need to continue.

This is the best advice I can give without knowing anything more about your application and its specific needs.

For most applications, software companies shy away from 3rd party binary plugins in the same process because when something goes wrong, it is very difficult to figure out why. Users usually blame the application, not the plugin, and the perception of the quality of your application is poor. It can be made to work by keeping very close relationships with your plugin authors, usually including exchanging all source code (optionally under restrictive licenses or NDAs).

Comment: While this doesn't answer the question (I was explicitly asking about documentation tools/techniques), it still considers some good points. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a standard way of documenting locking schemes using in university. 
1/ use diagram
you must draw a diagram. each point on the diagram is a lock link to other thread.

```
ex: T1      T2
     1 -R->  A
     2 <-W-  B
```

2/ use table
you must write down each point and thread on each row

```
ex:  T1         T2
     lockX(A)   lockS(B)
     read(A)    read(B)
     A<-A50     unlock(B)
```

Conclude: this is very complex task and take many time to trace.

Comment: Simple but might be quite effective.